# Change content of list in app indicator made using cappind

Tags: unity, bash, indicator, zenity

I made a simple indicator using cappind script which is based on zenity -

[Webupd8 article](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/zenity-for-appindicators-ubuntu.html)

[Capind page](https://sites.google.com/site/redaea/cappind-py)

I want to change the text of the list according to some condition..
Like, if the contents are -

```
This Mode
That Mode
```

I want it to be -

```
  *This Mode
   That Mode
```

OR

```
    This Mode
   *That Mode
```

Is it possible?